# CPP Error: Integer overflow in expression

Tags: c++, types

I'm trying to represent 16gb in bytes, and `uint64_t` throws an error.

What kind of data type should I use to represent it?
`unsigned long int` also throws an error.

```
error: integer overflow in expression [-Werror=overflow]
         uint64_t TESTBYTES = 16 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`uint64_t TESTBYTES = 16ULL * 1024 * 1024 * 1024` will do it.

Else the expression `16 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024` is evaluated as an `int`, with undefined results on your platform since you are overflowing the `int` type.

`ULL` promotes the first term to an `unsigned long long`, forcing promotion of the other terms. This is *always* safe since an `unsigned long long` needs to be *at least* 64 bits.

Comment: With what data type?

Comment: what is ULL? The other question being: If at somepoint I define another variable called `uint64_t TEST1BYTES` and adding 64bytes to it.. like TEST1BYTES+=64; It will throw an error once it reaches the limit.
BTW, Thanks

Comment: A `uint64_t` must wrap around to zero if you exceed the highest value, so no error would be thrown. But you'd do well to overflow a 64 bit unsigned by successive additions of 64; would take a few years even with an increment per nanosecond.

Comment: True that. Just asking - that's might happen.

Answer (score 1):

As-is your expression consists of [integer literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) without suffixes and will be evaluated as a signed integer and the value will overflow. The result of your expression is `17179869184` and the max value the 32-bit integer can hold is `2147483647` so it will overflow. To force the expression to be evaluated as unsigned (unsigned long long in your case) value you should add the `ULL` or `ull` suffix to one of your operands (except the final one as pointed out in the comments) so that the entire expression is evaluated as `unsigned long long`. Trivial example to demonstrate what happens:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    uint64_t x; // unsigned long long
    auto y = 16 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024; // evaluated as int, the result overflows
    auto z = 16ull * 1024 * 1024 * 1024; // evaluated as unsigned long long, does not overflow
    std::cout << "Your expression: " << z << '\n';
    std::cout << "Maximum integer value: " << std::numeric_limits<int>::max() << '\n';
    std::cout << "Maximum unsigned long long value: " << std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max() << '\n';
    x = z;
}
```

Comment: Not any one argument: adding it, say, to the final one makes the code vulnerable on platforms with 16 bit `int`.

Comment: this would still fail in both cases..
`uint64_t CapacityBytes[] = {16ULL * 1024 * 1024 * 1024, 16ULL * 1024 * 1024 * 1024};`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Could you please also address the above question?

Comment: The overflow is in the multiplication expression, not the deduction of variable type. It is not correct to say "the result doesn't fit" for the `y` line

Comment: @M.M: I think as an array the problem is with `error: too many initializers for ‘uint64_t [0]` not that we are having multiplication expressions.. because unint64_t[2].. works